# как получить предыдущую/следующую записи

Tags: php, sql

Всех приветствую! Есть php код, в котором я с помощью `GET` запроса получаю id новости, а потом добавляю кнопки перехода к предыдущей и/или к следующей записи через обращение к БД (в БД столбец id serial)

Принцип такой: если есть запись `id-1`, то кнопка `Предыдущая запись` появляется, аналогично и с `id+1`

```php
$prev_sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE id=" . ($_GET['id'] - 1);
$next_sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE id=" . ($_GET['id'] + 1);
$prev_result = $conn->query($prev_sql)->fetch_assoc();
$next_result = $conn->query($next_sql)->fetch_assoc();
if ($prev_result || $next_result) {
    echo '<div class="prev-next-btns">';
    echo $prev_result ? '<a class="nav-link" href="news_example.php?id=' . ($_GET['id'] - 1) . '">&#8592; Предыдущая новость</a>' : '';
    echo $next_result ? '<a class="nav-link" href="news_example.php?id=' . ($_GET['id'] + 1) . '">&#8594; Следующая новость</a>' : '';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Проблема в том, что при удалении записи пустой id ничем не заполняется, т. е. так и остаётся пустым. Например, есть записи 1, 2, 3. Я удаляю 2 запись. Новые записи будут начинаться с 4. Понимаю, что код, который я написал работает правильно, но как брать именно предыдущую/следующую **существующую** запись я не знаю

Думал, может написать триггер в БД, который будет сдвигать id на "-1" при удалении записи или пересмотреть сам запрос. Я ещё учусь, поэтому буду рад разумной критике

Comment: вы бы лучше новости по дате сортировали а не по id. В целом можете сделать `where id = ... union id > ... limit 1 union id <....  order by id desc limit 1` получите три записи

Comment: В самом деле, как я сам не догадался. Получился такой запрос: ```$prev_sql = "SELECT id FROM $dbtable WHERE id<" . $_GET['id'] . " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";```. С ```next_sql``` аналогично. Спасибо вам!

Comment: А что будет если в GET[id] передать `1 OR id > 1 --`?

Comment: @u_mulder, с решением, описанным в комментарии выше всё прекрасно работает. Если id=1, то предыдущая запись не находится и кнопка не выводится вообще

Comment: Я говорил не про `1`, а про строку `1 OR id > 1 --`.